# How to use Overlapped I/O with sockets?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, winapi, network-programming

I want to use Overlapped I/O in my server, but I am unable to find many tutorials on the subject (most of the tutorials are about Overlapped I/O with Completion Ports, and I want to use a callback function).

My server will have a maximum of 400 clients connected at one time, and it only send and receive data at a long periods of time (each 30 seconds a few kilobytes worth of data is exchanged between the server and the clients).

The main reason why I want to use Overlapped I/O is because `select()` can only handle a maximum of 64 sockets (and I have 400!).

So I will tell you how I understand Overlapped I/O and correct me if I'm wrong:

- If I want to receive data from one of the clients, I use `WSARecv()` and supply the socket handle, and a buffer to be filled with the received data, **and also I supply a callback function**. When the data is received and filled in the buffer, the callback function will be called, and I can process the data.
- When I want to send data I use `WSASend()`, I also supply the socket handle and the callback function, and when the data is sent (not sure if when placed in the underlying sent buffer or actually placed on the wire), the callback will also be called telling me that data was sent, and I can send the next piece of data.

Comment: I'd recommend using a library like `boost::asio`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one misunderstanding you appear to have is that OVERLAPPED callbacks are actually synchronous.

You said:

> When the data is received and filled in the buffer, the callback function will be called

Reality:

> When a call is made to an alertable wait function (e.g. `SleepEx` or `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx`), if data has been received and filled in the buffer, the callback function will be called

As long as you are aware of that, you should be in good shape.  I agree with you that overlapped I/O with callbacks is a great approach in your scenario.  Because callbacks occur on the thread performing the I/O, you don't have to worry about synchronizing access from multiple threads, the way you would need to with completion ports and work items on the thread pool.

Oh, also make sure to check for `WSA_IO_PENDING`, because it's possible for operations to complete synchronously, if there's enough data already buffered (for receive) or enough space in the buffer (for send).  In this case the callback will occur, but it is queued for the next alertable wait, it never runs immediately.  Certain errors will be reported synchronously also.  Others will come to your callback.

Also, it's guaranteed that your callback gets queued exactly once for every operation that returned `0` or `WSA_IO_PENDING`, whether that operation completes successfully, is cancelled, or with some other error.  You can't reuse the buffer until that callback has happened.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Reading from the network will never saturate even a single core, no matter how many sockets.  You might have associated computation that can, but you can distribute that to worker threads.  Don't need the I/O layer doing it for you.  Definitely don't need the I/O layer forcing you to use worker threads and pay for synchronization when the amount of computation doesn't justify it (glares at .NET base class library).

Comment: @HarryJohnston: And I'm sure that your fancy 10Gbs network cards (and their drivers) support DMA, which doesn't load your CPU.  While handing off work to worker threads can involve context switching, don't you think I/O completion ports have to do that too?  It's just a matter of wethehr it is under your control or the I/O layer.

Comment: DMA is a red herring IMO because it only affects the part of the I/O you have no control over anyway, and I would hope that getting IOCP packets to the best available thread is handled in the kernel.  But on second thoughts, I think you're right; if you use a lock-free queue to hand the jobs over to the worker threads, they can run full tilt, and it even avoids the kernel-mode transition involved in retrieving the next IOCP packet - so if anything it should perform *better*.

Answer (score 0):

The IO completion callback mechanism works fine, I've used it a few times, no problem.  In 32-bit systems, you can put the 'this' for the socket-context instance into the hEvent field of the OVERLAPPED struct and retreive it in the callback.  Not sure how to do it in 64-bit systems:(

Comment: By adding extra data after the OVERLAPPED structure... [Raymond Chen describes it here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/12/17/10106259.aspx) and more [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/12/20/10107027.aspx)  So don't abuse the hEvent.

Comment: @BenVoigt alignment issues:(

Comment: There's no issue.  You allocate your bigger structure correctly aligned, and its alignment is at least as good as the member OVERLAPPED structure.  And Win32 doesn't care if you pass it a pointer that happens to be overaligned.