# How to prevent WSASend() from blocking my UI thread?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, winapi, network-programming

I want to use Overlapped I/O with Completion Routine to handle client connections.

In my UI thread I want to use `WSASend()`, but in order for the system to call my callback function to inform me that data has been sent, the UI thread must be in a wait state, but this will freeze my UI!

How should I fix this problem?

Comment: Don't do this on the main thread

Comment: @David Heffernan So I should create another thread that calls `WSASend()`, and when my UI thread want to send data it should "tell" the other thread and give it the buffer to send? Of course this means that the callback function will be called in the context of the other thread.

Comment: That's the simple way. You could alternatively use a more capable message loop: http://www.wrongbananas.net/cpp/2006.09.13_win32_msg_loops.html  Personally I think I'd generally prefer to isolate this onto a different thread if at all possible

Comment: And if I want to receive data, I should also "tell" the other thread to call `WSARecv()` and give it all the information it needs: buffer - socket handle - etc.), is that correct?

Comment: I'm not sure. Sorry.

Comment: @Martin James I am talking about  I/O with Completion Routine and not I/O with Completion Ports.

Comment: Yes - I understand.  I meant 'I/O thread'.  Sorry, there have been a lot of IOCP questions lately and I got stuck.  It's too late for me to edit 'IOCP' into 'IO' now, but the rest of my advice is still valid:)

Comment: Oh - I can still delete it and repost:)

Comment: I agree with @DavidHeffernan - the UI thread should be doing UI things. The IO thread surely needs a binding and port, (server), or peer address and port(client). The socket from ConnectEx or AcceptEx is surely better loaded in the IO thread, but a Socket class with, (at this time, undefined), socket member could surely be created in the UI thread and signaled into the IO thread for handling. Whether buffers form part of your Socket class, or a separate Buffer class, is a design consideration.

Comment: @Martin James Yes, I understand that the UI thread do UI things, but my question is how should I move the `WSASend()` and `WSARecv()` to the other thread, because there are many factors involved: first i must "tell" that other thread to send data or receive data, second I must give it the socket handle and the buffer to send or use it to fill data on receiving, also there is the callback that needs to be executed in the context of that other thread. I am not sure if what I just said is how IO with Completion Routine is done, I can't find any examples that are not 10000 lines of code!

Comment: OK, I'll attempt an answer for those considerations:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @DavidHeffernan - the UI thread should be doing UI things. The IO thread surely needs a binding and port, (server), or peer address and port(client). The socket from ConnectEx or AcceptEx is surely better loaded in the IO thread, but a Socket class with, (at this time, undefined), socket member could surely be created in the UI thread and signaled into the IO thread for handling. Whether buffers form part of your Socket class, or a separate Buffer class, is a design consideration.

One implementation, (that I have used successfully):

Design/define an 'Inter Thread Comms', (ITC'), message class.  This has a 'command' enum member that can tell other threads to do stuff, together with any other useful stuff that might be required in such a message

Derive a 'Socket' class from ITC.  This has string members for the IP/port, the socket handle and anything else that may be required.

Derive a 'Buffer' class from ITC.  This has a 'BoundSocket' member, buffer-space and an 'OVERLAPPED' struct.

Comms with the IO thread is fairly easy. Since it has to wait on something altertably, it can wait on a semaphore that manages a 'Commands' ConcurrentQueue.

If you UI wishes to instruct the IO thread to, say, connect to a server, it creates a Socket instance, (new), loads the IP and Port members from UI elements, sets the Command enum to 'Connect', pushes the socket onto the Commands queue and signals the semaphore, (ReleaseSemaphore).

The alertable wait in the IO thread then returns with WAIT_OBJECT_0, (it needs to ignore returns with WAIT_IO_COMPLETION) and so knows that a command has ben queued.  It pops it from the Commands queue and acts upon the command enum, (maybe switching on it), to perform the required action/s.  For connect, this would involve an overlapped 'ConnectEx' call to queue up a connect request and set up the connect completion handler.

The connect completion handler, when called, checks for a succesfull connect and, if so, could new up a Buffer, load it, issue a WSARecv with it for the server to send stuff and store the returned Socket object in a container.  If failed, it could load the Socket 
with a suitable error message and PostMessage it back to the UI thread to inform the user of the fail.

See - it's not that difficult and does not need 10000 lines of code:)

The only thing I don't know how to do immediately is getting the 'this' for the socket object back from the OVERLAPPED struct that is returned in the completion routine.  On 32-bit systems, I shoved the Buffer 'this' into the hEvent field of the overlapped struct in the Buffer instance and cast it back in the completion routine.  The Buffer instance has a Socket reference, so the job was done.  On 64-bit systems, hEvent has not enough room to store the 48/64-bit 'this' Buffer pointer and, (aparrently), this required an extended OVERLAPPED struct:(  Not sure how that is done - maybe you will find out:)

[edit] @BenVoigt has advice on the 32/64 bit 'getting the Socket context 'this' back in the completion routine' issue - it's easier than I thought:):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28660537/758133

Comment: I should have put in the tags `C` and not `C++`, I will not create any classes :-). So the IO thread (the one that will execute `WSASend()` and `WSARecv()?`) will put itself in a wait state, but this wait state have two things that could "wake it up": 1) when the completion routine is called and finished executing. 2) the UI thread signalling it to wake up to do some IO stuff. Am I right about this point?

Comment: @John sure, at least two.  Maybe if you want to time stuff out, so it could have a non-infinite timeout and wake up on WAIT_TIMEOUT too.